# Are portable waypoints consumed when placed?

Tags: genshin-impact

Are portable waypoints consumed when placed, or is it sufficient to craft one, once unlocked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A brief Google search reported that sadly the Portable Waypoint gadget is not reusable and has to be crafted multiple times. Also, it only last for 7 days at max after being placed (or less if you remove it before expire date).

Once placed, there is no way to remove it and get a refund.

Apparently so far only the Wind Catcher, the NRE and the two Geo and Anemo **Treasure** Compass can be reused.

Source: [wiki](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Gadgets) and multiple post on the game official forum.